# How can I specify ENTER_FRAME so that the object enters on every 4th frame?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5, frame, enterframeevent

So the ENTER_FRAME property will add an object to the stage on every frame the game runs. If the game is 24 fps, 24 objects created per second. How can I limit that so it will generate an object every 4 frames?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can have a counter that increments every frame

```
var f:int = 0;
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onEnterFrame);
function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void{
    if (f%4 == 0){
        // do something
    }
    f++;
}
```

you can set `f=0;` inside the if statement if you like

Comment: Will f=0 mean that there will be no objects that are generated?

Comment: @GivenPie The only time f%4==0 is when f equal a number that divides by 4 with no remainder IE: 4/8/12/16. Modulus is basic math and you should understand it if you are going to do much coding.

Comment: Could even remove a line and do `if(0 == ++f % 4)`